# /events/index.html.erb:41: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^~~~~~

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I realize this is a common question probably but I'm having a rough day and I seem to be missing something basic in my code I googled around and I'm just not seeing the exact line of code that is causing the error.

my first if statement has an end (if current user admin)

@events do has an end

my second if has an end

```
  <% if current_user admin? %>
    <div class = "admincreate">
        <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'New event' , new_event_path(@events)%> </button> </p>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td class = "eventtitle"><%= event.title%> </td>
        <td class = "eventurl"><%= event.url %> </td>
        <td class = "eventbody"><%= event.body%></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title:</th>
    <th>Url:</th>
    <th>Body: </th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>

      <% if current_user admin? %>
        <div class =".btn-group-xs">
      <tr>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Show', event_path(event) %> </button>  </td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %> </button> </td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to 'Delete',event_path(event),
                      method: :delete,
                      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %> </button></td>
        </div>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
</table>

<%end%>
```

what am i not understanding? / missing?

Comment: It looks like your if has two ends... I think your formatting is pretty good, but if you were a little more strict with it the problem line would pop out more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray `<% end %>` in this section:

```
<% if current_user admin? %>
  <div class = "admincreate">
      <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <%= link_to 'New event' , new_event_path(@events)%> 
      </button> </p>
      <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I reformatted to make it more obvious. And why do you have a `<a>` tag *inside* a `<button>` tag?

Comment: Thank you guys , i will assume it is the end under the /button ?